# Iterate over the files of a directory

Tags: 20.04, bash

When I want to iterate over the files of a directory (directory `Runfirstall` for example) I usually do:

```
for folder in $DIR/Runfirstall/*
```

However I found the next sentence in some code:

```
for folder in $DIR/!(Runfirstall)/
```

Does this do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, provided the `extglob` shell option is set, the second one loops over all *directories* that are *not named* `Runfirstall`

From `man bash`:

> If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin,
> several extended    pattern matching operators are recognized.  In the
> following description, a pattern-list  is  a  list of one or more
> patterns separated by a `|`.  Composite patterns may be formed
> using one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> ```
>       ?(pattern-list)
>              Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>       *(pattern-list)
>              Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>       +(pattern-list)
>              Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>       @(pattern-list)
>              Matches one of the given patterns
>       !(pattern-list)
>              Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```